# Minecraft: Will not allow me to generate Plotme world

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-java-edition-server

I am adding a creative category to my own server using Plotme plugin. I followed the exact steps on this website: http://plotme.worldcretornica.com/how-to-use.html
but it still will not work. It simply says:

Starting creation of world 'creative'...

Then it says about 5 seconds later...

FAILED.

Anyone have any ideas about what to do? If you have any more specific questions about anything that might help figure out this problem, feel free to ask...
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, plotme is outdated. You should look for a newer and better alternative such as PlotSquared

(I assume you are using Multiverse) I have had this exact same problem on my server as well. It won't work unless you call the world `plotworld`. This might be something you can change in the config, not sure about that.

Comment: An alternative such as [PlotSquared](https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/plotsquared.1177/)